# Is it okay to do second job without telling my boss?

Tags: moonlighting

I want to take on a second job, because I need it the income. Is it okay to take a second job without telling my boss?

Comment: Many times when you signed a employment contract you opt for not doing dual employment in some countries this will held you legally.

Comment: Depends completely on your contract.

Comment: Where are you located?

Answer (score 13):

> Is it okay to take a second job without telling my boss?

This depends on your employment contract.

In my personal experience, when I worked a very large software company, I was required to sign an employment contract that I would not take a job performing similar work to my current job. Since I was a software engineer, I could not take on a job writing code, for instance. But I took on a teaching side gig which I argued was completely unrelated to my current job and thus not required to disclose it to my employer. Your mileage may vary.

Be sure check your employment contract and if in doubt consult a lawyer.

Comment: It actually also depends on jurisdiction. In germany, i.e., you need primary employers permission which he HAS to grand unless ther are reasons for not granting it (competition, working in total way too many hours). Not asking is a reason for immediate dismissal.

Comment: This is the right answer by far. It really boils down to the contract. Outside that, it's a free country and work is voluntary. You go where you please.